# What does 'gonna send a flood' mean in "This Is Me"?

Tags: song-lyrics, keala-settle

I was recently listening to the One Voice Children's Choir's cover of "This Is Me" by Keala Settle:

https://youtube.com/watch?v=uhzi7Shi2H0

Part of the chorus goes like this:

> When the sharpest words wanna cut me down
>   I'm gonna send a flood, gonna drown them out
>   I am brave, I am bruised
>   I am who I'm meant to be, this is me

Send a flood of... what? What does 'I'm gonna send a flood' mean?

Answer (score -1):

Others may disagree, but to me, send a flood means that you're using your inner positive voice to flood positivity and drown out negative comments others make.

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to why/how this interpretation fits the song?